# Figure with one caption below and one caption/legend on the side

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, legend

I'm looking for a way to add a legend to the side of my image, while still keeping my caption below.

I currently have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{
    This is my caption
}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
\end{figure}
```

Which results in the following image:

[image: screenshot of result of the above code]

So basically I'm now looking for a way to add a legend to the right or left side of the image. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of two sidy by side `minipage`s inside of the `figure` environment you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.725\textwidth}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
This is my legend. This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend. 
\end{minipage}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
This is my legend. This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend. 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.725\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.725\textwidth}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=4cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
This is my legend. This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend.  This is my legend. 
\end{minipage}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: minipage seems to be a good solution! Although the tabular from @Zarko would also work. Thanks both for the solution!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{XX}
\includegraphics[height=4cm, width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio,
                 valign=c]{example-image-duck} 
    &   Legend: some long explanation of image  \\
\caption{This is my caption in two lines}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
    &
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
or
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{XX}
\includegraphics[height=4cm, width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio,
                 valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &   Legend: some long explanation of image  \\
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{This is my caption in one line}
\label{fig:this-is-my-label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```